# Integrate iframed form into wordpress site with identity server

Tags: angular, wordpress, identityserver3

We currently have an Angular booking app that lets a customer login. When they click a login, they are redirected to a page on our identity server where the login. They are then redirected back to our app. 
What we would like to do is to iframe our app into a wordpress site and move the login functionality from the angular app to the wordpress site. 
Has anyone done anything like this? What do I need to do, as I'm not sure where to start. Looking for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Xo for Angular can help facilitate an integration between your Angular App and WordPress providing an extendable API.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Instead of using an iframe your entire theme would be your Angular App, managed by WordPress. This includes features like dynamic routing, templates, and an API providing easy access to pages, posts, menus, options, and more.

Check out the example theme to get started: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material

I am the author of the plugin and theme above.

Let me know if something like this would work for you, thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is really applcable for me. We have multiple sales websites in Wordpress and we want to embed a booking app by iframing it into the wordpress sites. But we need to be able to login to identity server on the wordpress sites and have the iframed booking app recognise that the user has logged in, so the user can then access their previous bookings.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe cannot solve your purpose .
To move the login functionality from the angular app to the wordpress site
You need a custom plugin which can do External Logins for you.
Its similar to Login via facebook google etc.
Expose angular app to create api then call api from Wordpress for login .

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad S.O. question! lol. My answer is that the question is in a flawed domain. You're asking a basic architecture question, not a technical one with a right or wrong answer.

Of course people have done something like this! This is a development "feature", and you should describe it in business terms, not technical terms. You will need to hire a developer to do this work. As Jin Thakur pointed out, you don't require an iFrame for this, so why are you asking about iFrames? Do you have an interest in iFrames, or do you have an interest in logging in your users? In Behavior Driven Development [BDD], we would create a feature using Gherkin, but you can use any business language you like.

```
Given that the site has an external login system.
And the users listed in the external login system are also tracted in the WordPress login system.
When a user logs into the external login system.
Then the user is re-directed to the WordPress site
And the re-direction URL contains a code that logs in the WordPress user.
```

Comment: I am the developer. I created a booking application in Angular. Business wants that embedded in all sales websites. They don't want to redevelop the application in Wordpress. Therefore my thought was to allow users to login to identity server in the wordpress sales sties and have that login carry over to the iframed. app.

Comment: OK, well then you have to explain how your app handles logins. The process would be to use a "shortcode", which is just a function. Then the shortcode would output the iframe, and some kind of identifier to log in the user in your app. A shortcode is rendered after the user is logged in in WordPress, so you could just output the user's ID if that is simple enough.